# Transform and filter through streams this java code

Tags: java, java-stream

I have the below code, and I would like to utilize the new java constructs such as streams, filters etc to simplify it.

Possibly something like

```
 eventsToBeProcessed = event.getRecords().filter(
   // filter all status that are finished
);
if (eventsToBeProcessed == null)

     return from function;

// loop through all the eventsToBeProcessed for processing
```

This is the code I currently have

```
 public Void handleRequest(final DynamodbEvent event, final Context context) {

     for (final DynamodbEvent.DynamodbStreamRecord ddbRecord : event.getRecords()) {
            Map<String, AttributeValue> map = ddbRecord.getDynamodb().getNewImage();
            if (map.containsKey("status") && map.get("status").equals("FINISHED")) {
                // Do something
            }
        }
  }

// return from function
```

Comment: Please read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

If you want to rewrite your `handleRequest` method by using streams, then you simply need to stream the `event.getRecords()`, invoke the `map` operation to map each record to the `Map` given by the `getNewImage()` method, filter for only the maps that contain the "status" key and whose value is equals to "finished". Finally, execute the operations you need in the terminal operation `foreach`.

```
public void handleRequest(final DynamodbEvent event, final Context context) {
    event.getRecords().stream()
        .map(ddbRecord -> ddbRecord.getDynamodb().getNewImage())
        .filter(map -> map.containsKey("status") && map.get("status").equals("FINISHED"))
        .foreach(value -> /*... do something ...*/);
}
```